# Xamarin not seeing my custom view

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a custom view called `SquareImageView` which I want to use in my xml file. But my xml can't seem to resolve it. Why? I've tried giving it the fully qualified namespace in lowercase

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <pokemonmobileclient.SquareImageView
      android:id="@+id/picture"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="15dp"
      android:paddingBottom="15dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="#55000000"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text.Style;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace PokemonMobileClient
{

    public class SquareImageView : ImageView
    {
        public SquareImageView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public SquareImageView(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public SquareImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        public SquareImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
        }

        public SquareImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            SetMeasuredDimension(this.MeasuredWidth, this.MeasuredHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

`<pokemonmobileclient.SquareImageView` has an underline saying `invalid child element pokemonmobileclient.SquareImageView`

Why can't I reference it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an intellisense warning if anything. This code should still work just fine. I believe that this is merely an error on the intellisense end saying that it cannot find one of these child elements as you are creating a custom view that extends one of these child elements.

[image]

As you can see this code works just fine:

[image]